Job Changed Pay From Per Foot to Hourly
I really need help understanding if what my job did was legal or not.
So about 3 months ago I signed this contract - LINKS BELOW
[To large to upload on post]
Page 1 - https://ibb.co/34J4DC2
Page 2 - https://ibb.co/k3G11VF
Page 3 - https://ibb.co/0BGLwgB
And so yesterday June 25, I go into work and we had about 4 new people starting that day. Boss sits us all down and tells us we are getting paid hourly and to top it off getting paid the same as the new guys. Mind you the only paperwork ive ever filled out was this contract, no W2, no 1099, nothing.
So is this legal what they did or?

a) legal question are a better fit for law.stackexchange.com b) laws vary greatly from one location to the next so any legal question needs a location tag. c) "is it legal" is rarely a useful question. "What are my options?" or "How do I deal with specific problem XYZ?" are a better fit here. d) the links did not work for me, picture is not displayed.

Based on W-2 and 1099 references, I added the US country tag.  If that is incorrect, please remove.

@Hilmar Law SE often closed questions in the form you suggested. Phrasing it hypothetically can avoid that problem.

FYI I am not clicking on any shortened link because of the potential exposure to malware.  This isn't due to a belief that the OP is trying to trick us, but is a general precaution.  I know that I could probably de-obfuscate the links myself, but I dislike being made to work when reading a question.

I don't understand the down votes. Unless we are punked, isn't this the type of person with a reasonable question? Suggest edits if there is a problem with the question.

I clicked the links and read the contract.
Let's be hyper-clear - you didn't have a job as an employee, you were a contractor. You were liable for taxes, insurance, etc. If you got hurt on the job, the default was that it was your problem not their's.
It is a crappy a deal as it gets and is shows they are a s****y company. This is from a business owner. They are the type of business that gives us all a bad name.
Since you are now hourly, if they are not now currently witholding taxes and had you fill out the appropriate state and federal paperwork - strongly consider finding a new job. It would mean they are LIKELY operating outside of legal status (IANAL).
This is the part where I say that I am not a Lawyer. I also say that I am a random internet person. I also am business owner and it pisses me off when businesses treat people the way they treated you with that the BS contract. The bottomline is unless you do work for multiple companies / people or intend to, you aren't a contractor, you are an employee with appropriate protections. This company seemed to deprive you of them. Again, I am not a lawyer.

In most if the US, you can be fired at any time, so your only real recourse to an upcoming job change change is to find work elsewhere.
You can probably get them to issue a corrected contract, for whatever that's worth.

In the US, being paid hourly is not salaried.

@cdkMoose: true. Fixed.
